# Errors occur in some specific mobiles on crashlytics

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, rx-java, crashlytics

There are some errors which only occur in some specific mobiles and that  are shown in crashlytics. In my mobile device app working fine but there are some mobiles where the screen is crashing. I am unable to identify how to resolve that issue without knowing the cause of error. For now it is showing me this error which I have pasted below.

This is the title on Crashlytics .

```
ConsumerSingleObserver.java line 49
```

and this exception is showing

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
   at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onError(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:49)
   at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:79)
   at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:123)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)

Caused by io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.CompositeException$a: Multiple exceptions (2)
|-- androidx.room.rxjava3.EmptyResultSetException: Query returned empty result set: select * from FamilyDetails where serverId=?
at b.g.i.a.f.i$g.call(FamilyDetailsDao_Impl.java:90)
|-- java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at b.g.n.d.q.i.k(ConsentStepViewModel.kt:2)
```

Comment: is your app live?

Comment: b.g.i.a.f.i$g.call(FamilyDetailsDao_Impl.java:90) <- you get an NPE here while you handle the empty query exception.

Answer (score 0):

`CompositeException` is usually thrown when your error handler itself throws an exception when it's handling an error thrown in the stream.

Make sure your error handling code is not throwing any exceptions.

Usually the stack trace will have the root cause below the `CompositeException`, prefixed with Caused by.